# Evaluating lists of attributes where some resources failed to become fully created

Tags: terraform

So... I have a case where I essentially do :

```
resource "openstack_compute_instance_v2" "foo" {
  count = N
  ...
  network {
    ...
  }
  network {
    ...
  } 
}

resource "ovh_domain_zone_record" "foo" {
  count = N
  ...
  target = "${openstack_compute_instance_v2.foo.*.network.1.fixed_ip_v4[count.index]}"
}
```

and everything is awesome... until it isn't.

If a resource creation for the instance fails with partial state, where the instance is created but not started, it is also not assigned anything under network.1.fixed_ip_v4

```
* ovh_domain_zone_record.foo: 1 error(s) occurred:

* ovh_domain_zone_record.foo[2]: index 2 out of range for list openstack_compute_instance_v2.foo.*.network.1.fixed_ip_v4 (max 2) in:

${openstack_compute_instance_v2.foo.*.network.1.fixed_ip_v4[count.index]}
```

so it seems that the problem here is that if resource with a count is resulting in an incoherent state throughout it's instances (some have a value on attribute, some do not), and that attribute is later referenced by another resource with same count to create an appropriate "sibling" resources (in my case DNS names for hosts) then the list resulting from ${resource.*.attribute} interpolation will not contain null entries where the main resource failed. It will instead be shorter from count by the failed amount, and consequently terraform will fail with number of failed resources as the last instances of sibling resources will not be able to get their information.

Secondly it would mean that if creation of main resource failed say for 2nd instance, creation of the related resource will fail for the third. As whole TF will then complain and not proceed at all, so it will not become wrongly created and is not really an issue.

The question is, how to create sets of related resources while using `count = N` ?

Comment: Seems like an issue with the openstack provider. Have you created an issue with them?